# node webkit doesn't launch with '#' in folder name

Tags: exe, node-webkit

I have the following node webkit version

```
nw.js v0.12.2
```

On Windows,when I run the nw exe from a folder which has `'#'` in it.e.g

```
C:\Users\user\Downloads\ #321\...\viewer\nw.exe
```

it opens a window with the list of files and directories in Downloads folder. Any idea why it behaves so ?

Also on MacOsx I am unable to launch it if I have a '#' in the directory name.
The error got is

> Uncaught ReferenceError:require is not defined 
>   Not allowed to load local resource:

I understand in both cases that special character is causing the problem but is this some sort of a command to Node webkit ? If there is any such reference it would be helpful to know that.

Comment: did you get the binaries from the git repo? 32/64? which win OS? I can run it without any issues.. tested version 0.12.2 64 on win8

Comment: It's strange, it works properly on win7 32 bit and Mac 10.9.5 64 Bit when downloaded from https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Downloads-of-old-versions and tested with '#' in it's folder name. I guess it might be something with the application I run with node webkit.